# html/css .css file changing <h1> color won't work

Tags: html, css, href

1. This is my html file

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>CSS cheat sheet</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csscheatsheet/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1> Hello World</h1>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. This is my css file

   ```
   h1 {
   color: green;}
   ```
3. You can see what I am trying to achieve at 10:44 mark. Just changing the h1 by changing the color, but it is not working. I have the same file names as the guy in the Youtube video. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfoY53QXEnI)

Comment: Your changes should be being applied, but it's possible you may have cached the stylesheet. Try a hard refresh with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Comment: Is the path to your stylesheet correct? Check the network tab of the browser's dev tools

Comment: You are referencing a file `csscheatsheet/style.css` are you sure this path is correct?

Comment: yes i am positive that is correct this is the path "href="csscheatsheet/style.css"  and there are no typo's in my file names i double checked and all the names are correct along with CTRL + SHIFT + R did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Try adding one more slash at the beginning:href="/csscheatsheet/style.css" , or refresh with Ctrl+F5

Comment: No that didn't work either :( try running the code yourself if you can it is just a. HTML and CSS file all the code is there just curious if my sublime text is the issue